# How to fix Net::SSLeay installed with Carton? XS issue

Tags: perl

We have `Net::SSLeay 1.55` installed into a 'local' directory, using `Carton` and `use lib`.

Everything is fine at compile time, but at run time when `Net::LDAP` desires to make a secure connection using `Net::SSLeay`, we get:

```
Can't locate object method "tid" via package "threads" at /usr/lib64/perl5/XSLoader.pm line 94.
```

Tried defining XS::Loader in cpanfile and installing that with Carton too, but although the locally installed XS::Loader is called, we still get the above error.

The problem is almost certainly related to [this Net::SSLeay bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=75487) (because we are, in fact, overriding `SIG{DIE}` in the program, which triggers the bug), but the bug was reportedly fixed in `Net::SSLeay 1.46`.

On our system, we have `/usr/lib64/perl5/auto/Net/SSLeay/SSLeay.so` (which is apparently used by the system `Net::SSLeay 1.34`) as well as the locally installed `SSLeay.so` for use by `Net::SSLeay 1.55`.  But perhaps the system `SSLeay.so` is being used?

How do we make sure the that `Net::SSLeay` is using the correct `.so` file (if that's why we still see the bug), or otherwise beat this error?

```
$ perl -v

This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
```

Comment: Looks like you're mixing threaded and non-threaded builds, e.g. running a threaded SSLeay.so on a non-threaded perl.

Comment: I think we're running threaded Perl... question updated with `perl -v` output.

Answer (score 0):

You either got a system-perl or a local::lib mixup.

Either someone is calling the system perl as executable instead of your private `$^X`, leading to the wrong module being called. Some people nowadays still believe there can only be one perl. From the limited info this doesn't seem to be your case.

Or someone is messing with `@INC`, preferring the wrong module path over your local `@INC`. Looks like you are calling the old system Net::SSLeay 1.34.

XSLoader usually ignores custom `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` overrides, so it cannot be this.

And there is an error in your question:
*On our system, we have /usr/lib64/perl5/auto/Net/SSLeay/SSLeay.so (which is apparently used by the system Net::SSLeay 1.34) as well as the locally installed SSLeay.so for use by Net::SSLeay 1.55.*

Your local Net::SSLeay 1.55 `SSLeay.so` cannot be in the system path. It is in your Carton local path. 
This should give you the compiled-in version:

```
$ strings /usr/lib64/perl5/auto/Net/SSLeay/SSLeay.so |grep ^1\.
=> 1.34
```

Answer (score 0):

Running perl v5.20.2 and Net::SSLeay 1.65 shipped with debian 8 I see the same behavior.
If you have your SSLeay.pm in `Canton`, you should have the the shared object file there also, along with the autosplit index file and the auto-loadable function files::

```
Canton/Net/SSLeay.pm
Canton/auto/Net/SSLeay/SSLeay.so
Canton/auto/Net/SSLeay/autosplit.ix
Canton/auto/Net/SSLeay/debug_read.al
...
```

Having `Canton` prepended to `@INC` either via `use lib` or the environment variable PERL5LIB, the .so file et al are loaded from there. You can make sure running `strace perl -Mlib=Canton -MNet::SSLeay -e 1 2>&1 | grep SSLeay`.

But as stated above, even with Net::SSLeay 1.65 I get the `die()` message from DynaLoader, if I set up a `$SIG{__DIE__}` handler prior to loading Net::SSLeay. I silence it like so:

```
use Carp;
BEGIN {
    $SIG{__DIE__} = \&Carp::croak;
}
...
# use Net::SSLeay; <-- this triggers the die message
BEGIN {
    local $SIG{__DIE__};
    my $mod = 'Net::SSLeay'; # or anything that uses N::S, e.g. Net::LDAP
    my $ret = eval "use $mod; 1";
    die "Can't load $mod: $@\n"
        unless $ret;
}
```

That's cumbersome, but at least it is a workaround which does the job.